# Did Yoda know (of) Snoke?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, snoke, yoda

I seem to remember reading somewhere that Snoke was something on the order of 1000 years old.  Yoda blew out (at least) 900 candles on his last cake.  It seems like there would've been plenty of opportunity for them to cross paths.

Perhaps Snoke was even Yoda's apprentice at some point and did the all-too-frequent turn to the dark side.

Comment: Since Snoke may be older than Yoda, perhaps Snoke was Yoda's master (who is unknown) before turning, rather than the other way around. Maybe Snoke is one of the Lost 20?

Comment: Yoda and Snoke were in romantic relationship for like 500 years..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no canon information on that **as of this point**.

As a matter of fact, we don't know if Snoke is old (assuming he watched G.E. rise as an adult, at least 70), the only thing we know for certain is that he predates the Galactic Empire:

> “Kylo Ren, **I watched the Galactic Empire rise**, and then fall. The gullible prattle on about the triumph of truth and justice, of individualism and free will. As if such things were solid and real instead of simple subjective judgments. The historians have it all wrong. It was neither poor strategy nor arrogance that brought down the Empire. You know too well what did.”
>   (TFA novelization)

Comment: Maybe snoke is plagues' force ghost?

Comment: @Escoce - discussed on another question

Answer (score 1):

There is a theory circling around out there that [Snoke is actually Darth Plagueis](http://newmediarockstars.com/2015/12/snoke-darth-plagueis-star-wars-force-awakens/). If this turns out to be true, it's very likely that Yoda did know of him.

Other than speculation like that, there's no established canon on the subject.

Comment: In *Episode I* when Qui-Gon Jinn says that they were attacked by "Sith Lord" on Tatooine, the council members express their doubt about it; one of members goes as far as saying "The Sith have been extinct for a millennium". If Yoda had ever met Plagueis, he would say something like "guys, Sith are totally real, I met one, like, 20 years ago". The only Sith contemporary to Yoda that he knew were Maul, Sidious, Tyranus and Vader.

Comment: "Difficult to see, the dark side is."

Comment: Yoda was NOT aware of Darth Plagueis. Indepedently of whether that theory is true